# How to install virtualenv in windows powershell

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv, conda, python-venv

I was installing `virtualenv.exe venv` in windows powershell.

I have anaconda in my windows machine

No LICENSE.txt / LICENSE found in source

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\python> virtualenv.exe venv
Using base prefix 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3'
  No LICENSE.txt / LICENSE found in source
New python executable in C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
```

Error is below

```
 raise OSError("Command {} failed with error code {}".format(cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command C:\Users\user\...v\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

Comment: What about just doing `python -m venv myvenv`

Comment: The issue might stem from that fact that it's using the default Anaconda Python, instead of a system installation. As an aside, why use venv if you already have Conda?